# Where should I install template scripts?

Tags: directory-structure, packaging

If I have a program that copies and modifies scripts or code-files as part of its operation, where should these other "default" or "template" scripts be installed?

Comment: Going by FHS, likely `/usr/local/share/$your_program_name/`

Comment: I just read the Wikipedia page for the Filesystem Hierarchy Standard. Based on that I think `/usr/share/$your_program_name` is the right spot. "Architecture-independent data", which is exactly what these files are. Thanks for the direction

Comment: @DeepDeadpool No `/usr/local/share`. `/usr/local` follows the same structure as `/usr` however it is for you to put your own stuff into. `/usr` is for the system installer to manage. Don't get in its way. `/usr/local` will not be touched by built in tools, so can be backed up and managed more easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/usr/local/share`, `/opt`, or users directory.

- `/usr/local` follows the same structure as `/usr` however it is for you to put your own stuff into. `/usr` is for the system installer to manage. Don't get in its way. `/usr/local` will not be touched by built in tools, so can be backed up and managed more easily.
- `/opt` is also (like `/usr/local`) for your own use. However if follows a different pattern. It is one directory per package, everything in one directory.
- You can also put it in your own directory. This needs no special permission, but will be harder for other users to know it is there.

Comment: Based  on your answer and jordanm's comment, I'm beginning to think I may not have been clear.

What I meant to say is that I've written a package that installs itself with a main program and a few template scripts. The main program will copy and then modify the templates when a user runs something like `myprog init`. I don't care about backing up the templates, as they are not personal to each user. /usr/local/share/myprog/ is really the place for these templates?

Comment: Probably the place for the template (`/usr/local` is not all about back-up, you also need to keep out of the way of the systems packages) (see also stow), but a copy should be made for each user, in their own directory.